# Laravel : json_decode returns null after ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I was trying to send query to the user. I have send the  query with ajax response to controller.
`$query` comes from editor which has html characters.I can't assign so i tried to decode but the problem is it convert it to NULL. How do i get the actual value?

```
$query = json_decode($request->Input(['query']), true);
$product = Product::where('name','=',$request->Input(['name']))->first();
$user= User::where('id','=',$product->auth_id)->first();
Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new Email($query));
return response()->json($query);
```

Ajax to call to controller ::

```
 $('#SupportForm button').on('click', function(e) {   
            query = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()
            console.log(query )
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: 
                {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{url("/supportEmail")}}',
                data: {'query ' : query ,'name':$("#support_product").val()}, 
                success: function(data) 
                    {console.log(data);},
                error:function(data)
                    { });
                });
```

Comment: Can you add query passed through ajax ?

Comment: share some sample values for query

Comment: if you want remove html elements use strip_tags()

Comment: Query Like : <p>Hello</p>

Comment: I don't want to remove HTML because I want to show as it is in mail view page.

Comment: Show your ajax code. It seems like from ajax its not pass as json

Comment: json_decode used for covert json string to php variable

Comment: use strip tag after send mail

Comment: I have updated with ajax code.please check it once.
@B.Desai

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in Laravel. And this did the trick for me

```
$result = json_decode($result->getContent(), true);
```